# Assign value to clob variable

Tags: java, oracle

Let's assume there is a variable CLOB response.
How do i assign some value to this clob variable in java?

I am doing this:

```
Clob clob=null;
clob.setString(0, "<test></test>");
```

The second line is showing an error saying clob could be only null here.

update-

```
ValResponses valResponses=new ValResponses();
          valResponses.setVraId(Long.parseLong("12"));
          Clob clob = null;
          //clob.setString(1, "<test></test>");
          valResponses.setFullResponse(clob);
          valResponses.setValReport(fileName);
```

See there is one pojo ValResponses  now this pojo has one variable valresponse having type CLOB,now I want to set some dummy value in that how to do that,?

Comment: Create from database connection like `Clob clob = connection.createClob()`.

Comment: @saka1029 not using database connection i want to assign some value to it like we do string eg-string a="1234";

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize the clob value like below an set the value(xml) to it

java.sql.Clob clobValue = oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(dBconnection, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

Comment: like we assign value to string a="12"; similarly i want to assign some value to clob type variable.connection will not be available there.

Comment: Please do not provide multiple answers. Instead use the `edit` link to change your original answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the simple approach to create the Clob

```
Clob xmlClob = con.createClob();
```

Comment: thanks for answer,But this variable is defined in pojo and now I am setting value in pojo in service .so say for example for STRING a=2 ,we assigning value there in service ;So how we will assign some value to that pojo variable in service.

Answer (score 0):

Get it from the `connection`object, then set the value in to it.

```
OracleConnection conn;  // initialize this first

CLOB clob = conn.CreateClob();
clob.setString(0, "<test></test>");
```

Or, another way to set the value

```
Clob myClob = null;
if (rs.next()) { //rs is ResultSet object
      myClob = rs.getClob(1);
      System.out.println("Length of retrieved Clob: "+myClob.length());
 }
```

Comment: here we are assigning value to clob from resultset,I just want to assign a dummy value,like we do for string eg-String a="123"; similarly a Clob c=?;

Comment: in that case, you have to go with the first approach

Answer (score 0):

Define a class implements java.sql.Clob as:

```
public class MyClob implements java.sql.Clob {
    final String value;
    public MyClob(String value) { this.value = value; }
    @Override public long length() { return value.length(); }
    @Override public String getSubString(long pos, int length) {
        return value.substring((int)pos, (int)pos + length);
    }
    @Override public Reader getCharacterStream() { return new StringReader(value); }
    @Override public InputStream getAsciiStream() { return null; } 
    @Override public long position(String searchstr, long start) { return 0; }
    @Override public long position(Clob searchstr, long start) { return 0; }
    @Override public int setString(long pos, String str) { return 0; } 
    @Override public int setString(long pos, String str, int offset, int len) { return 0; } 
    @Override public OutputStream setAsciiStream(long pos) { return null; } 
    @Override public Writer setCharacterStream(long pos) { return null; } 
    @Override public void truncate(long len) { } 
    @Override public void free() { } 
    @Override public Reader getCharacterStream(long pos, long length) { return null; }

}
```

And then

```
Clob clob = new MyClob("<test></test>");
```